# AngularJS replace complex select directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've implemented a select dropdown for filtering through a list of items. I'm looking to create a directive that will hide the select dropdown and replace it with a custom dropdown using the same options and maintaining the same functionality.

select:

```
<select ng-model="selectedLocation" ng-options="location.title group by location.group for location in locations | orderBy:['-group', 'title'] track by location.title">
    <option value="">Location</option>
</select>
```

locations Array:

```
[
    {
        title: 'New York',
        group: 'USA'
    },
    {
        title: 'California',
        group: 'USA'
    },
    {
        title: 'London',
        group: 'Outside USA'
    }
]
```

Desired output:

```
<div class="active">Location</div>
<div class="options">
    <span class="optgroup">USA</span>
    <span class="option">New Jersey</span>
    <span class="option">New York</span>
    <span class="optgroup">Outside USA</span>
    <span class="option">London</span>
</div>

// hidden, but value still binding to controller
<select ng-model="selectedLocation" style="display:none">...</select>
```

Any help in figuring this out would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried creating the custom directive? If so, what happens when you try to use it? Please include the code for your directive

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you check out the Select2 plugin for Angular...

GitHub Repo: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2

Demo Page: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-latest.html

Comment: If you have questions about implementation, create a Fiddle or Plunker and post the link

Comment: from the github repo: "ui-select2 is incompatible with <select ng-options>. For the best results use <option ng-repeat> instead."

Answer (score 0):

In order to put the exact same functionality into a directive here's a basic code snippet that would do that.

Remark: That's not the same as J.C.'s proposal to use angular-ui's select2 directive, which is a nicer and more powerful, but also more complex solution...

```
angular.directive('locationSelector', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<ng-form><select ng-model="selectedLocation" ng-options="location.title group by location.group for location in locations | orderBy:[\'-group\', \'title\'] track by location.title"><option value="">Location</option></ng-form>',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      'locations': '='
    },
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModel) {

      ngModel.$render = function () {
        scope.location = ngModel.$modelValue;
      };

      scope.$watch('selectedLocation', function (newVal) {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(newVal);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Use it like this:

```
<location-selector ng-model="location" locations="locations"></location-selector>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just recreate the same select? How would I be able to include the custom options here?

Comment: Yes, that would recreate the same select. That's basically the idea of directives: you encapsulate functionality that makes your HTML easier to handle and that you can re-use. Unfortunately Angular cannot do the magic to display a select without creating a select element in the DOM. ;-)
And yes, you can also add as many custom options here as you like - either via additional $scope variables (see locations) or via attributes. See the [directive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for further info...

Comment: excuse my ignorance, i'm fairly new to angular directives. will take a stab at this as well and lyk. thanks!

Comment: hey again @mbernath. I've managed to get the directive working and see that the select is being generated properly, but am still quite confused at how I would be able to apply custom styles to it – i'm still left with the same html select element. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xpSDlNW80V9sfeTcCWty?p=preview)

Comment: Hello Stephen, in your question you said nothing about custom styling. How to achieve that is a different question. Can it be done with simply styling the select via CSS? Is a custom solution required? Etc. I suggest you investigate a bit in that direction and look for code examples. Then you can just change your CSS and directive accordingly...